# How do I find number of NICs in my system?

Tags: wireless, networking, command-line

While trying to find number of NIC in my laptop, I found [this Superuser question on finding the total number of NIC's and ports attached on physical device](https://superuser.com/questions/677841/how-to-find-out-total-nic-cards-and-total-available-physical-ports-in-linux).

I got some commands to try on system : `$/sbin/ifconfig -a` ,when I tried this:

```
$ /sbin/ifconfig -a
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:26:55:b6:36:b3  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:17 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:843 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:843 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:70365 (70.3 KB)  TX bytes:70365 (70.3 KB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:1e:65:4f:c4:ca  
          inet addr:192.168.1.8  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::21e:65ff:fe4f:c4ca/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:9693 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:6750 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:4421067 (4.4 MB)  TX bytes:1042929 (1.0 MB)
```

Does it mean that I have two Ethernet cards or NIC's (is there is any difference between these two?), having physical addresses `00:26:55:b6:36:b3` and `00:1e:65:4f:c4:ca` respectively?

and when I tried `sudo dmidecode | grep -i "NIC"`, I got nothing:

```
$ sudo dmidecode | grep -i "NIC"
$
```

What does it mean?

When I tried `sudo dmidecode | egrep -i "PCI|Available|in use"` I got::

```
$ sudo dmidecode | egrep -i "PCI|Available|in use"
        PCI is supported
    Designation: PCI SLOT1
    Type: 32-bit PCI
    Current Usage: Available
```

I searched and found that `PCI (Peripheral Component Interconnect)` is a `32 bit bus`. Is it showing that I have a single slot?

Comment: wlan0 = wireless NIC, eth0 = wired NIC.. so yes, you have two Network Interface Cards. dmidecode doesn't do networking, it does BIOS data.

Comment: Thanx @ Grizly,, well what does no output for $sudo dmidecode | grep -i "NIC" signifies??

Comment: @jazzz try grepping for a different term, see update to my answer.

Comment: @muru ,,this too didn't worked anupam@JAZZ:~$ sudo dmidecode -t baseboard | grep Ethernet
anupam@JAZZ:~$

Comment: try without the grep and manually inspecting the output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way could be to use [`lspci`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/lspci):

```
# lspci | grep -i ethernet
00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82567LM-2 Gigabit Network Connection
01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82574L Gigabit Network Connection
```

Another would be to use [`lshw`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/lshw):

```
# lshw -C network | grep -i product
   product: 82574L Gigabit Network Connection
   product: 82567LM-2 Gigabit Network Connection
```

Considering the `ifconfig` output, yes, you do have two cards - one Ethernet and one wireless.

With `dmidecode`, you might need to look at a different place:

```
# dmidecode -t baseboard | grep Ethernet
Type: Ethernet
Description: Intel 82576 Ethernet 1
Type: Ethernet
Description: Intel 82574L Ethernet 2
```

Comment: This would not show wireless NIC's.

Comment: Thanx @muru ,,well it is showing only 1 Ethernet controllers that means ,I have a single ethernet card ,right?

Comment: @DanJohansen `lshw` would. `lspci` would need different greps for Ethernet and Network Controllers.

Comment: @jazzz single ethernet, yes.

Answer (score 1):

My network studies are a bit into the past, but as I see it, you have 2 phisical NIC's and one virtual. The "lo" is the virtual loopback interface all machines have with IP 127.0.0.1.

The 2 physical ones are the eth0 (which is a regular ethernet port) and wlan0 (which is your wireless device).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `lspci` but you need to grep for the PCI [NETWORK](https://pci-ids.ucw.cz/read/PD/02) class (02):

```
$ lspci -nn | grep '\[02'
00:19.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection [8086:1502] (rev 04)
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Centrino Ultimate-N 6300 [8086:4238] (rev 3e)
```